# Issues for count Xaxis PowerBi

Tags: date, powerbi, visualization

I use DirectQuery and want to use a clustered bar chart to display SUBJECT on the Y-axis and display dates on the X-axis. My issue is that when I place the dates on the X-axis, it defaults to displaying them using COUNT or any other SUMMARIZE function. Even though I set 'Don't Summarize' in COLUMN TOOLS, it continues to aggregate the dates. How can I solve this problem and display the dates in their natural form?